# Spring 3.2 MVC - Cannot match URL with Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I'm trying to start a new application from scratch with Spring 3.2, and I got the 404 error when I try to get access to my Controller. Here is my configuration:

```
WEB-INF
    web.xml
    web-context.xml
```

web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/application-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/web-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/deblan/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

web-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.deboralandini.web.controllers"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <beans>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
        </bean>
    </beans>

</beans>
```

My controller:

```
    package com.deboralandini.web.controllers;

    import ...;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("cuenta")
    public class CuentaController {

        @Autowired
        private CuentaService cuentaService;

        ...

        @RequestMapping(value = "/cCuenta")
        public String cCuenta(Model model){
            return "crearCuenta";
        }

        ...


    }
```

My index.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<html>
<body>
<h2>BlaBla</h2>
<br/>
<a href="cuenta/cCuenta">Crear Cuenta</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, when I click the link, I get:

```
Status HTTP 404 - /deblan/cuenta/cCuenta
```

The browser tries to make a GET to `http://localhost:8080/deblan/cuenta/cCuenta`, but I cannot get in my controller. I debugged the controller and in fact is not entering there, so: Whats my newbie error?

Thanks in advance
Marcos

Edit: this is my output:

```
"C:\...\App\tomcat8\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2014-10-21 08:57:21,069] Artifact DebLan:war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   ...
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64352', transport: 'socket'
21-Oct-2014 20:57:21.743 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.14
21-Oct-2014 20:57:21.745 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:   Sep 24 2014 09:01:51
21-Oct-2014 20:57:21.745 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:  8.0.14.0
21-Oct-2014 20:57:21.745 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:        Windows 8.1
21-Oct-2014 20:57:21.745 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:     6.3
21-Oct-2014 20:57:21.745 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:   amd64
21-Oct-2014 20:57:21.745 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:    1.7.0_55-b13
21-Oct-2014 20:57:21.745 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
21-Oct-2014 20:57:21.924 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init Cargada la biblioteca nativa APR de Apache Tomcat 1.1.31 con la versión APR 1.4.8.
21-Oct-2014 20:57:21.924 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init Capacidades APR: IPv6 [true], enviar fichero [true], aceptar filtros [false], aleatorio [true].
21-Oct-2014 20:57:22.551 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL inicializado correctamente (OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014)
21-Oct-2014 20:57:22.649 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
21-Oct-2014 20:57:22.662 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
21-Oct-2014 20:57:22.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 992 ms
21-Oct-2014 20:57:22.695 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Arrancando servicio Catalina
21-Oct-2014 20:57:22.695 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.14
21-Oct-2014 20:57:22.708 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
21-Oct-2014 20:57:22.719 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
21-Oct-2014 20:57:22.722 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 57 ms
Connected to server
[2014-10-21 08:57:23,165] Artifact DebLan:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[2014-10-21 08:57:32,003] Artifact DebLan:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2014-10-21 08:57:32,003] Artifact DebLan:war: Deploy took 8,838 milliseconds
21-Oct-2014 20:57:32.712 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio C:...\App\tomcat8\webapps\manager de la aplicación web
21-Oct-2014 20:57:32.762 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:...\App\tomcat8\webapps\manager has finished in 50 ms
```

Comment: Can you turn your logs to debug and check Spring's output?

Comment: Please enable Spring logging and try again.

Comment: It is too big and does not fit with the post requirements... What should I search for in the debug log? Thanks for the response...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If deblan is the context root then don't put it in the servlet mapping. You've got this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/deblan/cuenta/cCuenta
```

if you've deployed this app with deblan as the context root then:

```
http://localhost:8080/deblan
```

takes you to your app

/cuenta/cCuenta

now maps to your controller, so try:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Which means  `http://localhost:8080/deblan` + whatever comes after.

Comment: That works!!! But I don't understand why... Now I cannot get access to index.jsp, but when I try to go to http://localhost:8080/deblan/cuenta/cCuenta, the controller catches the request!

Comment: The reason it works is that the /deblan acts to get the request to your app. The servlet mapping tag is just interested in what comes after /deblan. Please accept my answer by checking the box under the up/down arrows and then we'll look at your index.jsp.

Comment: Ah what the heck. Change your url-pattern to / from /* and you'll probably get your index back. But please accept my answer by selecting the check mark under the up/down arrows.